# read | extract | export URI from qr code image with browser as a link | Is this possible with a tag, css class, some short js?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, tags, qr-code

qrcode image for scan or click.

Is it possible to read the qr code of an image with the browser without an add'on or extension and if i click to the image it will redirect me to the uri of the qr code.

I dont want to put the uri manually like:

```
<a href="qrcode-URI">
 <img src="qrcode.png" class="qrcode">
</a>
```

Is this possible with a tag, css class or some short js?

```
<TAG?>
 <img src="qrcode.png" class="qrcode NEWCLASS">
<TAG?>
```

or

```
<script>
 [CODE]
</script>
 <img src="qrcode.png" class="qrcode" #js action#>
```